# Kendo Grid duplication message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo grid and I have stopped the grid from saving duplicate values as follows in create method:

```
var results = new List<ProviderTypeMasterViewModel>();
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("ProviderTypeMastersController ProviderType_Create Start");
            foreach (var ProviderTypeMaster in ProviderTypeMasterList)
            {
                TblProviderTypeMaster ptm = new ProviderTypeMasterViewModel().ToModel(ProviderTypeMaster);
                var provd = _context.TblProviderTypeMasters.Where(p => p.ProviderTypeName == ProviderTypeMaster.ProviderTypeName).ToList();
                if (provd != null && provd.Count() == 0)
                {
                    if (ProviderTypeMasterList != null && ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        string userID = GetUserID();
                        providerTypeMasterService.SaveProviderTypeMaster(ProviderTypeMaster, userID);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    duplicate = true;
                    //Session["ErrMsg"] = "Already Exists";
                    //return RedirectToAction("ProviderType_Read", "ProviderTypeMasters");
                }
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("ProviderTypeMastersController ProviderType_Create Complete");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError("ProviderTypeMastersController ProviderType_Create Failed - " + e.Message);
        }
        return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
```

And in the read method I have displayed the error message to the user as follows

```
try
        {
            if (duplicate == true)
            {
                TempData["ErroMsg"] = "Already Exists";
            }
            _logger.LogInformation("In ProviderTypeMastersController ProviderType_Read");
            return Json(providerTypeMasterService.ListProviderTypeMaster().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError("ProviderTypeMastersController ProviderType_Read Failed - " + e.Message);
        }
        return View();
```

The duplication process has stopped. But I am unable to show the error message to the user. Can anyone let me know what I should do where I have gone wrong. I have tried using ViewBag,ViewData,TempData.

This is my View

```
<div>
if (TempData["ErroMsg"] != null)
{
    <p>@TempData["ErroMsg"].ToString()</p>
}
```

Comment: Your method is returning `Json` - you would need to include the error message in your `JsonResult` and then add it to the DOM in the ajax success callback (`TempData` is for passing data from one controller method to another when you make a redirect)

Comment: Can you kindly provide me a sample as I am new to this? Thanks in advance

Comment: I cant - you have not shown your ajax call for a start

Comment: Did not use any ajax here. Just used this in my kendo grid

Comment: .Create(create => create.Action("ProviderType_Create", "ProviderTypeMasters"))

Comment: Which is making an ajax call :)

Comment: So what should I do from here

Answer (score 0):

you can use DataBinding() and DataBound() function of kendo grid...these functions call in client side after Read method on server side..for example you can set a field and decision with this field